# Python - Parse SQL Query to return only fields names using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm trying to parse an SQL statement (stored in a file) and only save the name of the fields
so for the following:

```
SELECT
Involved_Party_ID=pt.ProgramId,
Involved_Party_Type=2, 
First_Name=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(pt.ProgramName, '|', '/'), CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(13), ' '),
Registration_Status=pt.RegistrationStatus,
Involved_Party_Status=CONVERT(SMALLINT, pt.ProgramStatus), 
Creation_Date=pt.CreationDate,
Incorporation_Country=CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CASE WHEN pd.IncorporationCountry='UK' THEN 'GB' ELSE pd.IncorporationCountry END),
FROM
    SomeTable AS pt
GO
```

The desired output would be:

```
Involved_Party_ID
Involved_Party_Type
First_Name
Registration_Status
Involved_Party_Status
Creation_Date
Incorporation_Country
```

Here's my code:

```
import re

File1 = open("File1 .sql", "r")
File2 = open("File2 .sql", "w")
    for line in File1:
        if re.match('\s*SELECT\s*', line):
            continue
        if re.match('\s*FROM\s*', line):
            break
        if re.match('(\n).*?(?=(=))', line):
            Field_Name = re.search('(\n).*?(?=(=))', line)
            File2 .write(Field_Name.group(0) + '\n')
```

I first tried using this regular expression:

```
'.*?(?=(=))'
```

But then my result came out as:

```
Involved_Party_ID
Involved_Party_Type
First_Name
Registration_Status
Involved_Party_Status
Creation_Date
Incorporation_Country
CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CASE WHEN pd.IncorporationCountry
```

Now that I've added `(\n)` to my regular expression the file returns completely empty although online regular-expression testing sites return the desired outcome.
[image]
(I'm not concerned about the whitespaces matching the regexp as I'm only retrieving the first result per line)

Comment: Your `line` only ends with `\n`, they do not start with `\n`.

Comment: `CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CASE WHEN pd.IncorporationCountry=` matches your regex (without the `\n`)

Comment: You could try anchoring to beginning of line instead and only searching for non-`=` characters e.g. `^[^=]*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the patterns you use with `re.match`, you can do without regex here. Just skip the line that starts with `SELECT`, stop matching at the line starting with `FROM` and collect the parts of lines between them before the first `=`:

```py
File1 = open("File1 .sql", "r")
File2 = open("File2 .sql", "w")
for line in File1:
    if line.strip().startswith("SELECT"):
        continue
    elif line.strip().startswith("FROM"):
        break
    else:
        result = line.strip().split("=", 1)[0]
        File2.write(result + '\n')
```

The output I get is

```
Involved_Party_ID
Involved_Party_Type
First_Name
Registration_Status
Involved_Party_Status
Creation_Date
Incorporation_Country
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/GDXjte).

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ox71jo/1)):

```py
s = """\
SELECT
Involved_Party_ID=pt.ProgramId,
Involved_Party_Type=2, 
First_Name=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(pt.ProgramName, '|', '/'), CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(13), ' '),
Registration_Status=pt.RegistrationStatus,
Involved_Party_Status=CONVERT(SMALLINT, pt.ProgramStatus), 
Creation_Date=pt.CreationDate,
Incorporation_Country=CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CASE WHEN pd.IncorporationCountry='UK' THEN 'GB' ELSE pd.IncorporationCountry END),
FROM
    SomeTable AS pt
GO"""

for v in re.findall(r"^([^=\s]+)=", s, flags=re.M):
    print(v)
```

Prints:

```
Involved_Party_ID
Involved_Party_Type
First_Name
Registration_Status
Involved_Party_Status
Creation_Date
Incorporation_Country
```